# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 on Xiaomi notebook pro

Tags: sound, alsa, 18.04

I am getting no sound after a fresh clean install of Ubuntu 18.04
Previously I run 17.10 and it was all good.

What I have tried:
- Checked all sound related settings
- Restart my laptop
- Uninstall / Install alsa and pavucontrol

The following is my sound card information:

```
>sudo lspci -v
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
Subsystem: Device 1d72:1701
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 148
Memory at b4320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at b4300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

In the sound setting panel, the indicator bar of current sound level still jump when I play youtube videos(chrome or firefox). Its just that there is no sound coming out. Sound test also did not produce anything.

Volume control turned up to max.

Comment: thanks to https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8fprpv/lost_sound_when_upgrade_from_1710_to_1804/ I were able to get some sound by messing with alsamixer

Comment: StackExchange questions do not use the [solved] convention for marking solution. I'll copy the information from the reddit thread so you can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open alsamixer and check if the channel has been muted.

Often it will show up there as muted even if it doesn't elsewhere.